# If statements in while loop ignoring list

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to make a text-based adventure game, and I'm a few days into learning Python. I plan to add to it as I go and use it to apply what I'm learning.

For some reason, although everything seems fine, Python started ignoring my "negative" list when I added a while loop to the start of the block. I can't figure out why!

```
# Error message printed if player types gibberish or doesn't pick one of the available responses.
def error():
    print("You must choose one of the options!")

# Allows going back to the beginning of the game should the player lose.
def begin():
    playerName = input("Enter your name: ").upper()
    print("This is a choose your own adventure game. %s, you have a great deal of danger ahead of you. This will require a lot of courage. Are you sure you are ready?" % (playerName))

# List of affirmative sayings the player may type (incl. alternatives to "yes").
affirmative = ["yes",
        "y",
        "yup",
        "yep",
        "sure",
        "okay",
        "rad",
        "yepper",
        "yeppers",
        "alright",
                ]

# List of negative sayings a player may type (incl. alternatives to "no").
negative = ["no"
        "n",
        "nah",
        "nu",
        "nope",
        "negative",
        "negatory",
        "go away",
        ]

begin()

""" If they aren't ready, gives them an epilogue and allows them to restart. If they ARE ready, allows them to continue. If they type gibberish, it makes them choose between one of the two options. """

while True:
    ans = input()
    if ans in negative:
        print("You never begin your journey. You stay at home and lead a completely normal, boring life. As the years go by, you find yourself reflecting more and more often on what could have been. The spectre of your unfulfilled potential haunts you until your death. :( ")
        newAns = input("Press Enter to start over.")
        if newAns == True or newAns == False:
            begin()
            break
    elif ans in affirmative:
        print("You begin your journey into a dark wood. Are there any supplies you'd like to take with you?")
        break
    else:
        print("You must choose! Yes... or no?")
        continue
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: In ```input``` , do you strip the whitespace  from the user's response before you return it?

Comment: In what way is it ignoring the list?  It works fine for me.  Of course, there's the slight detail that "no" doesn't appear in the list (you've constructed the French "non"), but that doesn't explain a full-bore "ignore".  Give actual output and expected result.

Comment: Just FYI, but that condition with `if newAns == True...` will never happen. What do you think the `input()` function returns?

Comment: I tried running it in 2, and it got an error as soon as I answered the prompt, because `input()` tries to evaluate the input (you need to use `raw_input()` in Python 2).

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5. Also, when I call my begin() function, nothing is printed and the "game" (what little there is so far) doesn't begin again! Why is that?

I thought input() would return a True (the user entered something) or False (the user entered nothing; None) value that I could use. Is there another way to do this? Does that question belong in a separate thread?

Comment: I solved the no-restart issue by simply removing the [code]if newAns ==True...[/code] line and putting [code]begin()[/code] where it used to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misplaced a comma after `no` in your `negative` list.

Change it to

```
negative = ["no",
            "n",
            "nah",
            "nu",
            "nope",
            "negative",
            "negatory",
            "go away",
            ]
```

Before, `no` and `n` would print your `You must choose! Yes... or no?` message because neither were technically in the list. Other responses like `nah` worked, though. Add that comma and you should be fine.

Comment: To amplify your point, the Python syntax `"string"<spaces, tabs, newlines>"second"` is parsed as `'stringsecond'` Thus, neither `'no'` nor `'n'` was in the list, but `'non'` was followed by `'nah'`.